# Long MP3 uploaded to Azure Speech-to-Text API returns no results after a significant period

Tags: azure-speech

I have uploaded a long MP3 file (around 8 hours) to Azure's Speech-to-Text API, using [this](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription). However, 16 hours later, there are still no transcript files available, using [this](https://centralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/GetTranscriptionFiles).

I have previously done the same process with a 7 hour long video and have received the results without any issues.

Is there a way to check the status of the transcription process?

Answer (score 0):

for us to check what is going on here, we would need to know the region and ideally the transcription ID... then we can look into our system and search for any information in the log files about the processing status ...

Comment: OK thanks, should I put them in the comments here or is there a better place to use?